# How can we create and run Zend controller request?

Tags: php, zend-framework, refactoring

PHP application has implemented Zend framework but not completely followed with Zend framework.

Non-zend code has the scope of Zend framework, so we can use it there.
I have a page in non-zend code, which includes another section file (reusable to other modules).

Now we want to refactor that section coding with Zend framework.

So, plan is to create and call Zend controller from existing included file and refactor existing code for zend.
Further zend controller will return the output of zend view to non-zend code (from where it's called) or flush the output of view to output buffer.

> So, basically we want to do something like this:
>
> - make zend controller object
> - set controller, action and query parameters
> - make request and get response from that object

Can anybody help me for that?